# access both params and query with zod

Tags: typescript, express, zod

the documentation for zod-middleware gives this example:

```
export async function endpointCode(req: TypedRequestBody<typeof bodySchema>, res: Response) {
  const typedBody = req.body;
  return res.json(typedBody);
}
```

it give nice access to body through `req.body` HOWEVER
i need to have access to both QUERY and PARAMS (not body, it was just in the doc so i pasted it for reference).
currently my router looks like this

```
exampleRouter.get("/:id/examples", processRequest({ params: FindExamplesParams, query: FindExamplesQuery }), findExamples);
```

How should the declaration of `findExamples` function look like if i want to access both query and and params?

for just query or just params its easy:

```
export async function findSomething(req: TypedRequestQuery<typeof SomeQuery>, res: ...)
```

but what do i do for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`zod-express-middleware`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod-express-middleware) also includes `TypedRequest` where you can pass the params, query, and body (in that order):

```
export async function findSomething(req: TypedRequest<typeof SomeParams, typeof SomeQuery>, res: ...) {
```

Comment: one issue, TypedRequest requires three arguments, what do i do if i dont actually need the body?

Comment: @Leo You could just pass `any` but I don't think TypedRequest *requires* 3. It has default values iirc